# What's wrong with this sentence: "Who am I doing this task with?"?

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

Imagine that you are in a class full of students and the teacher is forming couples to perform some task. Let's say, for some reason, you didn't hear the name of the person you are going to do the task with.

I would ask the teacher "Who am I doing this task with?" but Google shows me that there is no such a sentence out there.

How would you express yourself in this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Google is not supposed to have every utterable sentence. Try without 'task'.

Comment: Google does not show you that "there is no such a sentence": it shows you that it cannot find that sentence in its search base. But I'm sure Google will soon show you that there is such a sentence, because it will index this question! Even so, the fact that Google can or cannot find a sentence does not mean that it is correct or incorrect!!

Comment: Just to add some input: It might be more correct to say "With whom will I be doing this task?" (although most people don't actually speak this way)

Comment: @Chris Mukherjee: So who decides that it's 'more correct'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I agree - speakers make the language, not the other way round.

Comment: Bruno. It's all OK now! You can now use that sentence because it's now listed in [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Who+am+I+doing+this+task+with%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=4CBbUpLuCsXP0QWxvIFQ) (because Google has now indexed this question.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: All that I meant by my comment is that ending a sentence with a preposition is sometimes frowned upon (depending on who you're speaking to, or "to whom you're speaking"). Though it is not an actual rule in the English language, I agree with Mynamite that "speakers make the language, not the other way round."

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee: thank you for trying to make things clear to me. I would appreciate if you could tell me what you would have said instead.

Comment: @TrevorD: Google is one of the tools I use as a student  to check out whether a phrase/sentence exists or not. I agree that the fact that Google can not find a sentence does not mean that it is incorrect but the other way around shows me that it was used before which may help. Anyway, the question is "How would you express yourself in this situation?". I would appreciate if you could help me answering the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrunoChagas: Personally, if I were saying the sentence in an everyday scenario, I would say it exactly as you wrote it: "Who am I doing this task with?". However if I were talking to a professor or some type of professional, I might try to sound more formal, and in this case I would say: "With whom will I be doing this task?"

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee: I'm so glad I get it right. You definitely answered my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, Barrie, for your answer. So I could have used this sentence with no problem. But, what would you say in such a situation?

Comment: I'd say exactly that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was very useful and took away my doubt.